# VBA Update table/recordset in Access using Loop with values from another table/recordset?

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba, recordset

I need some help with some VBA for Access.

I have a table `"Client_Table"` with 100 rows of data. I have another table `"SalesRep_Table"` where I have 10 distinct Sales Rep ID numbers (such as: `AA1111`, and so on).

My goal is to run a procedure that takes the first ID record `"AA1111"` and places it in the appropriate column on the Clients table named `"AssignedSalesRepID"` for the first 10 rows, then the next ID number in the `SalesRep_Table` gets inserted into the next 10 cells in the `Clients` table, and the process repeats through a loop until all 10 IDs are now in 10 rows each to fill the 100 rows of data in the Clients table.

I went about it by creating two recordsets and trying a loop through SQL Update. However I end up with all 100 records containing just the last Sales Rep ID 100 times repeating. Can you take a look at my code and let me know where it needs to be fixed?

```
Public Sub Command01_Click()

Dim strSQL
Dim ClientsTableQuery, SalesRepList
Dim DataB as Database
Dim ClientQD as QueryDef
Dim SalesQD as QueryDef
Dim rstClient as Recordset
Dim rstSalesRep as Recordset

ClientTableQuery = "Clients"
SalesTableQuery = "SalesRepList"

'Creates a recordset with 100 client records named "Clients" 
strSQL = "Select * from Client_Table"
Set DataB = CurrentDB()
Set ClientQD.CreateQueryDef(ClientTableQuery, strSQL)
Set rstClient = DataB.OpenRecordset(ClientTableQuery)

'Creates a recordset with 10 sales rep records named "SalesRepList"
strSQL = "Select SalesRepID from SalesRep_Table"
Set DataB = CurrentDB()
Set SalesQD.CreateQueryDef(SalesTableQuery, strSQL)
Set rstSalesRep = DataB.OpenRecordset(SalesTableQuery)


rstSalesRep.MoveFirst
rstClient.MoveFirst

Do Until rstSalesRep.EOF = True

'SQL Query to update the top 10 cells in the "Assigned Sales Rep ID" column in the  
Clients recordset with the Sales Rep ID from the SalesRepList recordset

strSQL = "Update Clients, SalesRepList SET Clients.AssignedSalesRepID =   
SalesRepList.SalesRepID where Clients.ClientIDNumber in (Select Top 10     
Clients.ClientIDNumber FROM Clents where Clients.AssignedSalesRepID is Null)"

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
rstSalesRep.MoveNext

Loop
MsgBox "Finished Looping"
rstSalesRep.Close


End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I hate to be the one to tell you this, but you should reconsider using SQL to do this update.  I see that you have already written a lot of code and might feel like if you switch back to SQL that you will then have wasted all this vb code.  I have felt like that myself in times past.  But you can solve this problem with SQL with an order of magnitude less code(or nearly so).

Steps for SQL solution:

1. Sequence rows in both sets
2. mod A set sequence by B set sequence max
3. update A set on mod = b seq

Answer (score 2):

You are making a Join call in your query, without defining how those 2 tables are being joined. You are not mentioning anywhere, which record of the rstSalesRep recordset you wish to set the assignedSalesRepId to.

Also I would reduce all your code down to the following:

```
Dim strSQL
Dim DataB As Database
Dim rstSalesRep As Recordset

Set DataB = CurrentDb()

Set rstSalesRep = DataB.OpenRecordset("Select SalesRepID from  SalesRep_Table  ")
Do Until rstSalesRep.EOF = True

    strSQL = "Update Client_Table, SalesRep_Table SET Client_Table.AssignedSalesRepID = SalesRep_Table.SalesRepID " & _
    "where Client_Table.ClientIDNumber in (Select Top 2 Client_Table.ClientIDNumber FROM Client_Table where Client_Table.AssignedSalesRepID is Null)" & _
    " and SalesRep_Table.SalesRepID = '" & rstSalesRep("SalesRepID") & "'"

    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
    rstSalesRep.MoveNext

Loop
MsgBox "Finished Looping"
rstSalesRep.Close
```